Setting a custom colour theme in customtkinter
In a project, I am trying to change the colour template of my project from a list of pre-loaded .json themes saved to a folder user_themes. The themes are Anthracite.json, Cobalt.json and Blue.json. A drop-down menu is used to select the color and the template should load.
I tried this:
from customtkinter import CTkLabel, CTkButton, CTkOptionMenu, set_default_color_theme, CTk
root = CTk()
root.geometry("400x400")


def click():
    CTkLabel(root, text="Here is some text").pack(pady=20)


def new_color_theme(nct: str):
    print(nct)
    set_default_color_theme(f"user_themes/{nct}.json")


btn = CTkButton(root, text="Click me", command=click).pack(pady=20)
lst = ["Anthracite", "Cobalt", "Blue"]
menu = CTkOptionMenu(root, values=lst, command=new_color_theme).pack(pady=20)
root.mainloop()

But this is not working. The theme is getting printed but is not reflected in the window. What could be the reason for this and any suggestions to correct it?

Is the file found from the working directory? A better way to go about this would be to populate the options from the found theme files.

I can find no indication that set_default_color_theme() can be usefully called after the startup of your program.  It just sets some global data, that widgets make use of when they are created - it does absolutely nothing to change the theme of existing widgets.  (The one thing I see that does affect existing widgets is set_appearance_mode() - but your only choices there are "light" and "dark".)

Ok, so by that, you mean that once the window is created, even if you change the set_default_color_theme the theme remains same. Is there a work around this, like suppose destroying the window and generating it again

Ok, the problem here is that the function is customtkinter's.
So this is your script:
set_default_color_theme(f"user_themes/{nct}.json")

It doesn't work, instead use:
import customtkinter
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme(f"user_themes/{nct}.json")

